# Parallel processing in R shiny, calling Python script

Tags: python, r, parallel-processing, shiny, doparallel

I am trying to do parallel processing in R shiny, the parallel task which I want to do is a call to python script. However it does not work and not able to fetch the result back from python to R.
Below is the sample R shiny and Python code.
App.R

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Sample Program"),

      mainPanel(
         uiOutput("txtValue")
      )   
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  source_python("../../PythonCode/Multiprocessing/multip.py")  

  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type='PSOCK')
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  result <- foreach(i=1:5) %dopar% fsq(i)
  stopCluster(cl)     
   output$txtValue <- renderUI({
    result   
   }) 

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Python Code (multip.py)

```
def fsq(x):
    return x**2
```

Comment: Where does `source_python` come from? What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: the python function call is not executed, it gives error at the line  result <- foreach(i=1:5) %dopar% fsq(i)

Comment: the source_python is to reference the python script,  it comes from reticulate package.   the error message is "Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is independent of `shiny`:

```
library(reticulate)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(parallel)

source_python("multip.py")  

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = 'PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)

# throws: Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% fsq(i)

stopCluster(cl)
```

I interpret this such that one cannot serialize a Python function as one can serialize a R function. A simple workaround is to use `source_python` within the loop:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = 'PSOCK')
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
  reticulate::source_python("multip.py")  
  fsq(i)
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: this worked, thanks ! yes, it makes sense to have complete code for the parallel task inside the loop especially when it is referencing an outside script/function

Comment: To expand on Ralf Stubner's answer: the `fsq` R function relies on an object of type `externalptr`.  Such objects cannot be serialize/unserialized unless the developer behind such objects have implemented support for it. (I yet have to see an example of that.)